# Auth via cookies, storing the admin id too

Tags: php, security, cookies, authentication

I am testing a way to autenticate via a private system with cookie.

Consider i have a db like this:

```
 adminID - user - email - psw
```

Whenever someone logs in i set a cookie like this:

```
$adminID . 'i' . md5($email.md5($psw)); // Example: 12iAbsca89d2n2j321j312n3j2j2kn
```

So when the website notices the presence of this cookie it select the id from the cookie, in this case 12 and then check the corrispondences of `Absca89d2n2j321j312n3j2j2kn` with `md5($email.md5($psw))` from db where adminID = 12

Do you think it's bad? if yes why?

I am testing this for performance-wise, becasue i can do a select on the primary field (adminID) without having to create an other field indexed in my table

Thanks

Comment: extremely bad idea. you might as well not have an authentication system.

Comment: please refrain from doing this comment and explain why. The only issue i see here is if someone steal the cookie from someone other's pc

Comment: how about anyone sniffing traffic on the network? It's trivial to grab cookies, and once I have one, I send it from my browser, your website grants me whatever authority user with adminID=12 has.

Comment: Using session there is the same treats...

Comment: You are correct. The point is, any cookie based auth system is subject to hijacking unless you encrypt your cookies. Hashing the id is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on just how secure you want your site to be. That approach is better than a lot I have personally seen, however, it is ripe for cookie hijacking, all somebody has to do is snoop the traffic and copy your cookie and viola, they have access. For small sites, the likelihood is probably very small though. Really, the only way to be totally secure, is through proper use of sessions. This has the downside of not keeping you logged in between visits, so you will end up logging in more often, think your bank's website or eBay.

Comment: my website isn't a bank :) I really don't need that kind of security.

Comment: Thats perfectly understandable, I do something similar for my site to keep me logged in. You may want to consider using sessions, and the cookie for backup between sessions. Also, think adding something more secure than md5, look at the `hash` function, specifically `hash('sha512', $email.$psw)`

Comment: @yes123 You "don't need that kind of security"? A glib comparison to a banking website is **not** how compare your security risks. Do you know and understand what the impact would be to your users if it was compromised? Because that's how you start evaluating how secure it needs to be.

Comment: Also, the comment about the bank wasn't about the level of security, just how the logins work, where they only remember you for an hour or so of idle. I doubt any of us are going to create a level of security on par with banks :P

Comment: to add security to this solution now at every login i store the remote ip in a field of the admin' table... when somoneone got that cookie the website automatically check if the ip stored = current remote ip. So if soemone steal the cookie would not be logged because of the different ip

Comment: Unless they spoof your IP too :P

Answer (score 1):

Why store in a cookie when you have SESSIONS that aren't accessible (viewable, editable) to user?

My suggestion - store only users' id in the session.

```
session_start();

//Logging in (checking for $_POST data etc., validating password)
if(do_log_in()){
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  echo "User is logged in!";
}
```

Comment: The $_SESSION variable is not shared across different servers, so coding against this really makes scaling to more than one machine hard.  I recommend using memcached, membase or mysql (slow compared to the other two).

Comment: @yes123 yes they do, but they use only 1 cookie with the sessions ID, and it doesn't give much sense to users which increases security.

Comment: @Saurav, sorry, didn't get your thought, could you explain it, please?

Comment: @briedis: what's the differnces if someone steals the session cookie or my cookie?

Comment: @Briedis.  I'm glad you asked. When most websites grow, the first thing they do is add more app servers.  But the app servers don't share data stored in the $_SESSION variable.  So one request may go to server1 and the other to server2, to only crap out since server2 has no idea what server1 saved in it's $_SESSION variable.  Some sites will enable sticky sessions (more work to setup) to get around it, but then failover is hard.  Membase avoids this by keeping the data in a distributed manner (and redundant with Membase) so that app servers can go up and down w/out killing the service.

Comment: @yes123  You're out of luck if someone grabs a session cookie, no matter what scheme you come up with.  However, you can make it  really hard to hijack a cookie by encrypting all your traffic and enabling HttpOnly cookies.  You can also limit the damage of a hijacked cookie by expiring sessions.

Comment: Ok so basically using session i do't add security to the system than my custom cookie.. If somone steals my cookie or the sessipn cookie the treat is the same... I could add security by storing the ip in the table (and that's what i do) in the moment of login

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look over some of the notes and examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping only a session id and using memcached to store the session data.